# how and why container and its image is getting deleted automatically?

Tags: linux, centos, docker, java

I have a zeppelin container running on centos7 and on every couple of days the container and its image is getting deleted automatically, and every time i have to to docker compose up -d.

[here is the log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gT95K-b1jy3V-77mwlgkZa8Li7VnxLX0-5kWIRs1xx8/edit?usp=sharing)

the docker-compose yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  dev-zeppelin:
    image: zeppelin-docker:latest
    container_name: dev-zeppelin
    hostname: dev-zeppelin
    user: '0'
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/logs
      - ./notebook:/notebook
      - ./interpreter:/interpreter
    ports:
      - 8888:8080
    environment:
      - ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR=/logs
      - ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR=/notebook
      - ZEPPELIN_INTERPRETER_DIR=/interpreter
    logging:
      driver: journald
      options:
          tag: zeppelin
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify whether your system has any restrictions on the number of containers that can be produced and whether such restrictions have been achieved.Examine the system to see if there are any memory or resource restrictions that might be causing the container to be removed.

Comment: below are the suspicious tasks before Shutting down the zeppelin

Jan 02 06:02:01 xxxxxxxx CROND[197871]: (root) CMD (find /tmp/. -maxdepth 1 -mmin +10 -type f -delete)
Jan 02 06:02:01 xxxxxxxx CROND[197881]: (worker) CMD (php72 /data/cli/worker/bin/booking.php health all >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 02 06:02:06 xxxxxxxx zeppelin[30081]: INFO [2023-01-02 05:02:06,628] ({Thread-23} ZeppelinServer.java[lambda$shutdown$0]:316) - Shutting down Zeppelin Server …

but i am not sure those tasks are the culprit